# Transfer ERC20 Token from Address A to Adress B with web3

Tags: node.js, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

1.2.6 of the web3 library and I am trying to interact with a standard ERC-20 token on the Ropsten Text net using the infura node. Even though I manage to succesfully broadcast the transaction it gets reverted. The error message I constantly receive is the following: "Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:"

When I am interracting with the contract via remix it works fine. Please see the full code below:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/cb1****");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);


/* NETWORK AND LIB VERSION CHECKS*/
web3.eth.net.isListening()
   .then(() => console.log('web3 is connected'))
   .catch(e => console.log('Wow. Something went wrong'));
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
.then(console.log);

// Create an async function so I can use the "await" keyword to wait for things to finish
const main = async () => {
  // This code was written and tested using web3 version 1.0.0-beta.26
  console.log(`web3 version: ${web3.version}`)

 /* ADDRESSES */ 

  var myAddress = "0x77Bd******"; 
  var destAddress = "0x4f*****";
  var contractAddress = "0x67b7fecf8b02506d4692d9895959c42d7e7511bb";
  var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './abi.json'), 'utf-8'));
  // var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress, { from: myAddress });
  var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, contractAddress);


/* INPUTS TO RAW TRANSACTION */ 

 // 1.Nonce: Determine the nonce
 var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
 console.log(`num transactions so far: ${count}`);

  // 2.token amount - token is divisible to 0 decimals hence 1 = 1 token
  var transferAmount = 10000;


  // How many tokens do I have before sending?
  var balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
  console.log(`Balance before send: ${balance}`);

  // I chose gas price and gas limit based on what ethereum wallet was recommending for a similar transaction. You may need to change the gas price!
  var rawTransaction = {
      "from": myAddress,
      "nonce": "0x" + count.toString(16),
      "gasPrice": "0x003B9ACA00",
      "gasLimit": "0x250CA",
      "to": contractAddress,
      "value": "0x09",
      "data": contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, transferAmount).encodeABI(),
      "chainId": 0x04
  };

  let privKey_ = "CDA******";
  let privKey = new Buffer.from(privKey_, "hex")
  var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
    //var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction,{chain:'rinkeby', hardfork: 'petersburg'} ); // https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61771/error-returned-error-invalid-sender
    tx.sign(privKey);
    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();


 console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);
  var receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));
  console.log(`Receipt info:  ${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}`);


  // The balance may not be updated yet, but let's check
  balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
  console.log(`Balance after send: ${balance}`);
}

main();
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add " Handle Revert: true " to your transaction options. This according to the web3 documentation, will output the revert reason.

I faced the error for a long time and only solved it by changing the addresses I was using. I guess there was no synchronization on the EVM somehow, with the current setup I had